# git push only one file to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

Is it possile to only push one file to Heroku, instead off all changed files?

Thanks...

Comment: ... so you could deploy a .gitignored file like google api's "credentials.json" without having to track it in source control. this would be an amazing feature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Git tracks content not files, so you push all or nothing.
If there are files that you don't want to ever push, add them to the `.gitignore` file.
If you've already committed them however, you would still push them for that commit, but any later changes will be ignored.

Comment: This explanation could be better. Git thinks of history in terms of commits, and when you push, you're pushing commits to the remote. A commit by definition represents a state of your entire work tree not, just one file. It doesn't matter whether git is tracking content or files; a commit still represents *all* of it, and can't be dissected to push.

Comment: Your comment about the gitignore is also a bit off. If you've already committed files, adding them to the gitignore won't do anything (this has been asked a thousand times on SO). You need to also remove them from being tracked (`git rm --cached`) and commit that removal, or git will continue to treat them as normal. The gitignore is only applied to untracked files.

Answer (score 3):

If you commit only that one file then it is the only one that will be pushed.

Answer (score 0):

You can commit single files

```
user@mypc~$ git add single/path/to.file
user@mypc~$ git commit -m "si"
```